# CreateInstanceAndUnwrap throws TypeLoadException for present, valid assembly

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-assembly

I'm trying to use a new application domain to load application plugins/mods in a more isolated/restricted setting.

It's been a real uphill battle because this in Mono 2.0 (Unity3D) and most examples I can find for C# 4.0+.

I *was* getting a FileNotFoundException when loading an assembly with `domain.Load(...)` but based on [this article](https://www.broes.nl/2012/09/assembly-load-and-filenotfoundexception/) that happens because the assembly is "crossing domains" since the assembly itself is returned. So taking that article's advice I'm trying `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` instead.

However, now I get:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Fake.Namespace.TestMod.TestMod'.

```
// Create a new domain to load this dll in
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestingDomain", null,
new AppDomainSetup {
  ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(dllFile),
});

IMod mod = (IMod)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("TestMod", "Fake.Namespace.TestMod.TestMod");
```

`TestMod` is the name of the assembly. `Fake.Namespace.TestMod.TestMod` is the correct namespace and classname of the primary class:

```
namespace Fake.Namespace.TestMod {
    public class TestMod : MarshalByRefObject, IMod {
        public TestMod() {
        }
    }
}
```

The only advice I can find is to verify the assembly is present (it is, removing it causes this to throw a FileNotFoundException), has the namespace/class, and there's no duplicate in the GAC (this is just a simple DLL I threw into a project directory).

What else could I be missing?

CreateInstanceAndUnwrap needs Read/PathDiscovery permissions, which I believe I'm setting correctly:

```
var ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
ps.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

var f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
ps.AddPermission(f);

var f2 = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
f2.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery;
ps.AddPermission(f2);

var policy = PolicyLevel.CreateAppDomainLevel();
policy.RootCodeGroup.PolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement(ps);

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain", null,
new AppDomainSetup {
    ApplicationBase = basePath,
});
domain.SetAppDomainPolicy(policy);
```